# Problem with flutter application executed on a PDA?

Tags: android, flutter, dart-pub

I developped a small android application with Flutter on a PDA (mobile computer)
my problem is i can't receive a scanned barcode on text box. 
With the same PDA i have not this problème whene i develope the same app with java android

Comment: That's not a lot of information.

Comment: Thanks for your response my problem is that I have a form with one formfieldtext and when I scanned a barcode with my laser scanner pda I don't  have any thing into my text box nb. My pda''s name is bluebird.

Comment: Other things with Java android i have not this problem on the same pda. Exuse my poor English